# Cannot connect to home server in multi router setup from outside networks

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, port-forwarding, home-server

My friends cannot connect to my home server. It´s port forwarded, but if I test the port connection with YouGetSignal, it tells me that the port is closed. I have a Tp Link powerline network, and the transmitter (TL-PA8010P(EU) Ver. 3) is linked to my primary router (Speedport Smart 3). My second router(EasyBox 803) in the living room is connected to TL-PA7010(EU) Ver.1,my bedroomis connected to a TL-WPA8631P(EU) Ver.3 wich is a w-lan repeater and finally in my basement, the server(Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) connected to another TL-PA7010(EU) Ver.1. The port for the server is only forwarded on my main router because it´s not possible to forward the server on the other two routers.

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT? Based on your initial description, it does appear that you might be, which means you won't be able to forward traffic on a specific port from outside of your network to a device within your own network.

Comment: What's your external IP Address? [Leave the last figure out if it bothers you]

Comment: I looked it up, and my router website is showing me another ip address for my computer than "https://whatismyipaddress.com/". When I didn't have this powerline network, everything worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It no longer has any value - Router restart

Answer (score 0):

I'm so dumb. A router restart just did the trick. I apologize for wasting anyone's time with this post.
:(